# Android lollipop sdcard location Unable to make .zip file

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, zip, permission-denied

I try to make .zip file in sdcard location but I found this error.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/.sdf.zip: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I know I have to take permission for this and I already took.
My rename delete write and make folder function are correctly worked but stuck in ZIP file.
This is my code

```
try {
    System.out.println("OutZipFilePath is = "+outZipPath);
    fileoutObject = new FileOutputStream(outZipPath);
    bufferOutObject = new BufferedOutputStream(fileoutObject);
    zos = new ZipOutputStream(bufferOutObject);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    verifyStoragePermissions((Activity)cntxt);
}
```

Comment: what about this.. http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-programmatically-zip-and-unzip-file-in-android

Comment: If /storage/sdcard1 indeed points to a removable SD card then you can expect exceptions as those cards are read only under lollipop. So you cannot create folders either. So clear up please.

Comment: greenapps :: i can make folder nd file on sdcard loliipop but cant create ZIP file and fileoutObject = new FileOutputStream(outZipPath); i got error